# Where to start learning Distributed Systems programming?

Tags: network-programming, cloud, distributed-system

I'm a recent grad with a CSS degree and I never had a chance to take a course on distributed systems, but have progressively become interested in the topic. I would love to dive into the subject head-first in hopes of beginning my career as a software developer in that field. I've taken an Operating Systems course and have knowledge of multithreaded programming, along with elementary knowledge of distributed systems concepts, but that's about as close as I got to the subject, which isn't close at all.

Does anyone know a good place to start learning about the subject for someone with a CSS degree?

Do I really need a strong background in distributed systems specifically to get an entry-level job or do you think there are companies willing to hire people with strong programming skills but not necessarily strong knowledge of distributed systems?

Comment: You should check this question on Quora that is really exhaustive (705 upvotes) : [http://www.quora.com/What-are-some-good-resources-for-learning-about-distributed-computing-Why](http://www.quora.com/What-are-some-good-resources-for-learning-about-distributed-computing-Why)